# jQuery gradient plugin?

Tags: jquery, gradient

Is there any good jQuery gradient plugin. I found one, but it uses old jQuery, when I use latest, so it probably won't work with latest version.

Comment: Good question - I've been wondering this myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont know if you've already tested these plugins:

**JQuery Gradient Plugin:**

http://www.ajaxupdates.com/jquery-gradient-plugin/

**JQuery Gradient Plugin II**

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/gradient

I hope you can use one of them.

---

Here is a third, more up to date, jQuery gradient plugin

**JQuery Gradient Picker**

https://github.com/tantaman/jquery-gradient-picker

Comment: Hi, I tried those and those use oledr jQuery. So I don't think those will work with latest jQuery...

Comment: the first one uses jQuery v1.3.1 / the latest one is 1.3.2 - I tested it with 1.3.2 and it works perfectly.

Comment: The first link appears to be broken (403 Forbidden when accessing http://www.ajaxupdates.com/jquery-gradient-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a background gradient plug-in, but  textgrad may help when horizontal gradients need to be applied to text

http://www.si-les-idees-suffisaient.net/jquery/textgrad.html

Comment: This link also appears to be broken (non-existant when accessing http://www.si-les-idees-suffisaient.net/jquery/textgrad.html)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my one, [radass](https://github.com/r043v/radass)

[demo](http://radass.limpidia.net/)

[integration example in fabricjs](http://past.is/noBD)