# CSS create color gradient

Tags: css

Is there a way to create a color gradient in CSS without using an image file?

I am trying to give a DIV a background with a color gradient so that it looks glossy.

Answer (score 7):

Safari (Webkit) supports it:
http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/

Firefox 3.6+ supports it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient

W3 spec defines support for it:
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#gradients-

And you can use **Modernizr** to detect support and fall back on an image:
http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#cssgradients

Comment: Hm, and WebKit went ahead and invented their own syntax different from the W3 one. Genius. But still, keep in mind that the alleged "definition" is no more than a draft, so the W3C hasn't defined anything, they're still pondering how it might look like.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are using or can use **PHP**

http://snipplr.com/view/26070/multicolor-gradient-generator/

http://www.designdetector.com/2005/09/css-gradients-demo.php

See **javascript** solutions here

[jQuery gradient plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472422/jquery-gradient-plugin)

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1014-Creating-Transparent-Gradients-With-jQuery.htm

**Some gradient image generator**

http://www.roundedcornr.com/

http://gradient-maker.com/

http://www.grsites.com/generate/group/4000/

http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/gradient/

http://www.allcrunchy.com/Web_Stuff/Gradient_Generator/

**71 Gradient Resources for Web Design**

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/gradient-resources/

Answer (score 2):

Sure Is (using color: Royal Blue, Hex Code: #002366 as an example (example taken from: http://www.99colors.net/name/royal-blue):

```
<div class="gradient">[Your DIV text and what not]</div>

/* CSS Background Gradient */
.gradient
{
    background-color: #628AD9;
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Chrome, etc) */
    background: #628AD9 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#001640), to(#628AD9)) no-repeat;
    /* Mozilla,Firefox/Gecko */
    background: #628AD9 -moz-linear-gradient(top, #001640, #628AD9) no-repeat;
    /* IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#001640, endColorstr=#628AD9) no-repeat;
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#001640, endColorstr=#001640)" no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Webkit browsers support pure-CSS gradients like this ([see this example in Safari or Chrome](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/LayoutTests//fast/gradients/simple-gradients.html?format=raw)) - but practically speaking for a cross-browser implementation you'll need to use images.

Comment: While still using images, a flexible solution: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/supereasyblendys/

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,e5e5e5+100;White+3D

You will see it generates the following code for the displayed glossy gradient there. You can change the gradient and copy the new code.

```
 background: rgb(255,255,255); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(229,229,229,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```