# how can we use and control Gradient

Tags: html, css, filter

i use this as a background bar ... repeated of course

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3c2f75b680.gif

and i want to replace that with simple CSS Gradient color without image ...so i searched all over the internet and i found this:

```
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(endColorstr='#ffffff' ,startColorstr='#000000'  , gradientType='0');
```

, but this is not enough .. then i searched in StackOverFlow.com 
and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054940/css-create-color-gradient) ,very close to my question..

first i opened [this](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/) , but the examples didn't show any gradient with me(it appears just text .. and there is no gradient)...

then i opened [this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#gradients-), and i have been trying this:

```
linear-gradient(top, yellow, blue 20%, #0f0);
```

on div:

```
<div style="width: 633px; height: 268px; background:linear-gradient(top, yellow, blue 20%, #0f0);">
</div>
```

didn't work also...

1. i check out the photoshop and i sow somethign in gradient called "Opacity Midpoint".. is it avalible in CSS .. if it is , how to use it?
2. in `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(endColorstr='#ffffff' ,startColorstr='#000000'  , gradientType='0');`  how to put a limit for the startColorstr?
3. how to use `linear-gradient(top, yellow, blue 20%, #0f0);` and `radial-gradient(bottom left, farthest-side, red, yellow 50px, green);` in CSS?

**note:**one simple good answer would be OK , but i would like to know all of these ... thanks

Comment: Which browsers do you expect this to work on/what are you testing on? Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first, the `filter` property is available in Internet Explorer only. It won't work in any other browser.

Then there is no CSS standard that specifies gradients; there is a working draft that is part of CSS 3 but it's far from complete and thus the functions `linear-gradient` and `radial-gradient` are not yet widely available and may be subject to radical changes anyway.

And WebKit did entirely its own thing, apart from everyone else.

That's the current state concerning gradients in CSS and even if browser vendors implement the CSS working draft, the property and function names will be prefixed with `-moz-` or `-webkit-`, etc. They are not meant to be used freely on the web, actually. It's more a tech preview of what might come but things might very well change and the final property/function is named differently anyway (without the prefix).

If you need parametrized gradients, then probably your best bet is to write a script which creates them according to several arguments.

Comment: oh, thanks for the good info+1, but i am using Internet Explorer ..and it didn't work?!!

Comment: jjj: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752%28VS.85%29.aspx – in IE 8 the `filter` property has to be prefixed with `-ms-` so it becomes `-ms-filter` which is in line with the requirements for custom CSS properties by browser vendors.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that there isn't a reliable, cross-browser way to do gradients without an image as of yet.

- the `filter` only works in IE
- There's `-webkit-gradient` which only works in some browsers
- There's also the new [`<svg>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) which, again doesn't have any sort of consistent implementation.

If you're still really set on this, the only other choice is to generate them using javascript ([see this site](http://slayeroffice.com/code/gradient/) for an example).

Comment: Why do you drag SVG into this? First of all you can't embed literal SVG into CSS anyway, so the usage is pretty much akin to using an image. Second, while the different implementations have varying success in following the specification something as simple as gradients can be expected to work reliably. There are far worse things in SVG that are hard to implement. Still, the SVG tag has nothing to do with CSS, nor HTML so it's a little out of place here.

Comment: thanks.. but i did see that js code , it is long script ...i need simpler than that